# Non-empty previous value - MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, sharepoint-2013, dimension, performancepoint

I am using Performance Point Dashboard Designer 2013 and SharePoint Server 2013 for building dashboards. I am using SSAS2012 for Cube.

I have a scenario similar to the one illustrated by figure below. I am required to find Previous Non-Empty value for purpose of finding Trends.

[image: Previous Non-empty]

**Measure: [Quota]**

**Dimension:  [Date].[Calendar Date].[Date]**

The script `([Measures].[Quota], [Date].[Calendar Date].PrevMember)` gives you a previous date. Lets say for date 27-Jan-13 whose Quota value is 87, it returns 26-Jan-13 which has null value. I want it to return 21-Jan-13 that has some Quota value. And for date 21-Jan-13, I want to return 15-Jan-13.

I wonder if this is possible.

Thanks,
Merin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After long searches and hits & trials and so on, I think I invented a solution of my own for myself.

Following is the script for my Calculated Member.

```
(
 [Quota],
 Tail
  (
   Nonempty
   ( LastPeriods(15, [Date].[Calendar Date].PrevMember)
    ,[Quota]
   )
  ).Item(0)
)
```

Explanation

1. The number 15 means it will look for non-empty measures up to 15 siblings.
2. Now we know up to how many siblings to traverse back, in this case 15.
3. Lets find 15 previous siblings (both empty and non-empty) excluding current member.

   > (LastPeriods(15, [Date].[Calendar Date].PrevMember)
4. Since it will yield both empty and non-empty members, lets filter out empty members in terms of measure [Quota]. If we don't specify measure here, it will use default measure whatever it is and we may not get desired result.

   > Nonempty(LastPeriods(15, [Date].[Calendar Date].PrevMember),[Quota])
5. We may have several members in the output. And we will choose the last one.

   > Tail
   >     (
   >      Nonempty
   >      ( LastPeriods(15, [Date].[Calendar Date].PrevMember)
   >       ,[Quota]
   >      )
   >     )
6. So far, the script above gives previous non-empty member. Now we want to implement this member for our measure [Quota].

Hence we get the script below ready to create a Calculated Member.

```
(
 [Quota],
 Tail
  (
   Nonempty
   ( LastPeriods(15, [Date].[Calendar Date].PrevMember)
    ,[Quota]
   )
  ).Item(0)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion to define this.

The following query delivers something similar for the Adventure Works cube:

```
WITH member [Measures].[Prev non empty] AS
            IIf(IsEmpty(([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.PrevMember, [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])),
                ([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.PrevMember, [Measures].[Prev non empty]),
                ([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.PrevMember, [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
               ), format_String = '$#,##0.00'

SELECT {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], [Measures].[Prev non empty]}
       ON COLUMNS,
       non empty
       Descendants([Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2007]&[12], [Date].[Calendar].[Date])
       ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE [Customer].[Customer].&[12650]
```

You would have to replace the name of the date hierarchy, as well as the measure name from `Internet Sales Amount` to `Quota` in the recursive definition of the measure `Prev non empty`.

Comment: Thank you FrankPI. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi Frank. I have one more question. I have a date dimension from year 1985 to 2015. That is too much dates. And I have measure available only for five dates. So this query took about 3 minutes to yield result. Is there anything we can do for the recursive function to traverse to only non-empty dates rather than traversing through all dates. Thanks!

Comment: @MerinNakarmi One solution cold be to move this calculation to the cube processing so that the measure would be available instantaneously when you access it: Instead of just loading `Quota` for five dates, you could make it available for all dates e. g. via a view from which you read the fact table containing this measure.

Comment: I tried to create a Calculated Member inside a cube using your idea but unfortunately it did not work. Maybe I wrote it incorrectly. I will try it again. Thanks FrankPI.

Comment: @MerinNakarmi Moving the calculation to a calculated member in the cube would not help much, as the things defined in the calculation script are evaluated at query time. My suggestion was to move the process to the data loading time - which is called "processing" in Analysis Services terms.

Comment: Yes FrankPI. You are right.
Running this Query in Query Editor yields desired result but is very slow.
Creating a Calculated Member yielded nothing.
Could you please enlighten me on how to do it in data loading time. 

Thank you very much.